# When uploading large file to ftp server using php page crashes

Tags: php, html, file-upload, ftp

I have the following problem, I am uploading 33.3MB file using HTML5 filedrop. First I save the file to local storage and then I transfer it to ftp server. the page crashes after about 1 minute,(after the file is saved to local storage). I noticed that it continues uploading, every time I refresh the page I see that the file size increases. Finally it is uploaded in background but my of course I do not want the page to be crashed. If someone knows the reason please reply me. I have increased upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and I increased timeout too.

```
$userName = "username";
$pass = "pass";
$root = "FolderBBB";


ini_set('default_socket_timeout', '1000');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize',  '1024M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '1000');
ini_set('max_input_time', '1000');
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); 

$conn = ftp_connect("path",2121,1800) or die("Could not connect");
if (ftp_login($conn, $userName, $pass)){
    @ftp_pasv($conn,TRUE);
      set_time_limit(0);
        if ($_FILES && $_FILES["file"] && $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]){
            $fullPath = $root.$_POST["path"]."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
            if (ftp_exists($conn, $fullPath)){
                echo "{\"check\": false,\"text\":\"File already exists on server.\"}";
            }else{
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                    // echo $root.$_POST["path"]."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
                    if(ftp_put($conn, $fullPath, $_FILES["file"]["name"], FTP_BINARY)){
                        unlink($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                        echo "{\"check\":true, \"text\":\"File(s) were uploaded successfully.\"}";
                    }else{
                        echo "{\"check\": false, \"text\":\"File ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." was not uploaded successfully.\"}";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "{\"check\": false, \"text\":\"File ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." was not uploaded successfully.\"}";
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Add this before uploading code `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: It crashes anyway in about 20 seconds, but file upload continues in background, even if I close the page.

Comment: Than there must be some other reason of crashing you have to share your code so that we can have better idea.

Comment: I have added code to my question. Is there something which may cause page crash?